# MyRectangle2D math problems, check if rectangles contain each other and overlap

Tags: java, oop, object

I'm doing an exercise out of Introduction to Java 9th Edition by Y. Daniel Liang.
The exercise is 10_13. The one where you have to program the MyRectangle2D class.

I have have programmed the class and it runs smoothly but the problem is, when I submit the program to the LiveLab, I am getting a score of 1. A score of 1 means the program runs correctly but you are getting the incorrect output.

When I submit the program this is what I get:

Area is 26.950000000000003

Perimeter is 20.8

false

true

true

Which is incorrect according to the LiveLab.

Here is my program, can someone please tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks

```
public class Exercise10_13 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    MyRectangle2D r1 = new MyRectangle2D(2, 2, 5.5, 4.9);
    System.out.println("Area is " + r1.getArea());
    System.out.println("Perimeter is " + r1.getPerimeter());
    System.out.println(r1.contains(3, 3));
    System.out.println(r1.contains(new MyRectangle2D(4, 5, 10.5, 3.2)));
    System.out.println(r1.overlaps(new MyRectangle2D(3, 5, 2.3, 6.7)));
  }
}
class MyRectangle2D
{
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double height;
    private double width;

    public double getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(double x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public double getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(double y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }
    public void setHeight(double height)
    {
        this.height = height;
    }
    public double getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }
    public void setWidth(double width)
    {
        this.width = width;
    }
    public MyRectangle2D()
    {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.height = 1;
        this.width = 1;
    }
    public MyRectangle2D(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public double getArea()
    {
        return width * height;
    }
    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        return (width * 2) + (height * 2);
    }
    public boolean contains(double x, double y)
    {
        return (2 * Math.abs((x-this.x)) > height || 2 * Math.abs((y - this.y)) > width);
    }
    public boolean contains(MyRectangle2D r)
    {
        return (2 * Math.abs((r.getX()-this.x)) > height || 2 * Math.abs((r.getY() - this.y)) > width);
    }
    public boolean overlaps(MyRectangle2D r)
    {
        return (2 * Math.abs((r.getX()-this.x)) >= height || 2 * Math.abs((r.getY() - this.y)) >= width);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contains methods appear (to me) to be in error. For one you seem to be swapping width and height in them, since x is related to width not to height, and visa versa for y. Also, why the `2 * ...` in those equations? Also, are you sure about your `>` and `<` use in these methods? You may wish to think through the logic of these methods on paper first before committing them to code.

Next, you might want to format your numeric output to simplify the results and get rid of the long mantissa.

i.e.,

```
System.out.printf("Area is %.2f%n", r1.getArea());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I took yours and @aaa advice and got it working. The reason for the 2 * ... is because I had the mind set of thinking that since theres four sides it should be 2 + x - this.x etc.

Comment: @user2178846: aaa's advice is wrong. I am not the one to down-vote him, but regardless, it's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
public boolean contains(double x, double y)
{
    return 2*Math.abs(x-this.x) < height && 2*Math.abs(y - this.y) < width;
}
public boolean contains(MyRectangle2D r)
{
    return contains(r.getX(), r.getY()) && contains(r.getX() + r.getHeight(), r.getY() + r.getWidth());
}
public boolean overlaps(MyRectangle2D r)
{
    return contains(r.getX(), r.getY()) || contains(r.getX() + r.getHeight(), r.getY() + r.getWidth());
}
```

Comment: I got the right answer by using this piece of code and taking @Hovercraft Full Of Eels advice by taking out the "2*Math.abs() in the equation.

Comment: My original solution was not to use the abs(), but thought it might be more elegant. Now I realize where my error was. it's supposed to be Math.abs(2(x-this.x) - height) < height rather than 2*Math.abs(x-this.x) < height. Same with the other expression. Overall, it's not elegant as I initially imagined.